# How to integrate react-dnd into admin-on-rest?

Tags: drag-and-drop, admin-on-rest, react-dnd, react-admin

Has anyone tried to integrate react-dnd or another lib into admin on rest?
I wanted to make datagrid draggable inside a referencearrayfield.

Should i write my own component overriding datagrid or there's a simple way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a requirement for the app I'm building too. Starting here: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/1836 . I may report back once I have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement a custom datagrid for that

Answer (score 0):

Although experimental you can have a look on this plugin: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-tree-ui-materialui

It has as dependency react-dnd and it seems that it is editing the listing. Not sure if it can update a property used for ordering like `order` for example